# onClickListener on a CardView in a RecyclerView created by a Fragment in a Fragment in an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

This is a multi-part question.

**First Part:**

I'm building an app to track local events. Currently, I have a Fragment containing a RecyclerView consisting of CardViews which each represent one event. What I want is to be able to tap a card and replace the Fragment with a new one showing more details about that card's event.

I've searched Google for several hours, but it none of the solutions presented seemed to work when I tried them.  Below is the class for the fragment Tab1 which creates the RecyclerView adapter.

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
//RecyclerView
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

//ProgressDialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "removed";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_EVENT = "event";
private static final String TAG_EVENTNAME = "Event Name";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "Location";
private static final String TAG_RAINLOCATION = "Rain Location";
private static final String TAG_ORG = "Org";
private static final String TAG_TIME = "Time";
private static final String TAG_RSVP = "RSVP";

// events JSONArray
JSONArray events = null;
private List<Event> eventlist;
private RecyclerView rv;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2,container,false);

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetEvents().execute();

    return v;
}
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
}

private class GetEvents extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                eventlist = new ArrayList<>();
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                events = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_EVENT);

                // looping through All Events
                for (int i = 0; i < events.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = events.getJSONObject(i);

                    String eventName = c.getString(TAG_EVENTNAME);
                    String location = c.getString(TAG_LOCATION);
                    String rain = c.getString(TAG_RAINLOCATION);
                    String org = c.getString(TAG_ORG);
                    String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);

                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, h:mm a", Locale.US);
                    SimpleDateFormat parserSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
                    try {
                        Date date = parserSDF.parse(time);
                        time = format.format(date);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String rsvp = c.getString(TAG_RSVP);

                    eventlist.add(new Event(eventName, time.toUpperCase(), location, R.drawable.pace));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(eventlist);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
}
```

And here is the RVAdapter

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.EventViewHolder> {

public static class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cv;
    TextView eventName;
    TextView eventTime;
    TextView eventLocation;
    ImageView orgPhoto;
    private ClickListener clickListener;


    EventViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        eventName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
        eventTime = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
        eventLocation = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_location);
        orgPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.org_photo);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public interface ClickListener {

        /**
         * Called when the view is clicked.
         *
         * @param v view that is clicked
         * @param position of the clicked item
         */
        public void onClick(View v, int position, String title);

    }

    /* Setter for listener. */
    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onClick(v, getPosition(), eventName.getText().toString());
    }
}

List<Event> events;

RVAdapter(List<Event> events){
    this.events = events;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_card, viewGroup, false);
    EventViewHolder pvh = new EventViewHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EventViewHolder EventViewHolder, final int i) {
    EventViewHolder.eventName.setText(events.get(i).name);
    EventViewHolder.eventTime.setText(events.get(i).time);
    EventViewHolder.eventLocation.setText(events.get(i).location);
    EventViewHolder.orgPhoto.setImageResource(events.get(i).orgPhoto);

    EventViewHolder.setClickListener(new EventViewHolder.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v, int pos, String title) {
           //onClick
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return events.size();
}
}
```

You can see I've attempted to implement the interface and onClickListener.
Is this the right way? I've tried to test it by making toasts with the name of the Card clicked, but it doesn't appear to have worked, or at least the toast is not showing up.

**Second Part:**

If this is the correct way and it should be working, where/how do I write the code to replace the fragment with the new one showing more information about the event? Can it go in the Adapter class? The Tab1 fragment is actually inside of another fragment which is inside of an activity. I'd like to replace Tab1's parent fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.EventViewHolder> {

public static class EventViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cv;
    TextView eventName;
    TextView eventTime;
    TextView eventLocation;
    ImageView orgPhoto;


    EventViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        eventName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
        eventTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
        eventLocation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.event_location);
        orgPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.org_photo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //do stuff
    }
}

List<Event> events;

RVAdapter(List<Event> events){
    this.events = events;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public EventViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.event_card, viewGroup, false);
    return new EventViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EventViewHolder EventViewHolder, final int i) {
    EventViewHolder.eventName.setText(events.get(i).name);
    EventViewHolder.eventTime.setText(events.get(i).time);
    EventViewHolder.eventLocation.setText(events.get(i).location);
    EventViewHolder.orgPhoto.setImageResource(events.get(i).orgPhoto);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return events.size();
}
}
```

For the 2nd part of your question. Its better for the ParentActivity hosting both Frag1 & Frag2 to switch the fragment. So say in the ParentActivity, there is a framelayout (R.id.container) that is hosting Frag1.

You can pass the event call back to the activity, and you can do this to replace the fragment in the container

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container, Frag2)
    .commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can you explain what itemView.setTag(holder) is supposed to do? Because holder is set = to getTag() above and  doesn't resolve. Also, the class EventViewHolder wants to implement the abstract method onClick, but you have it outside the class. Why is that?

Comment: You need to do this itemView.setTag(holder); in the constructor code for EventViewHolder to bind the itemview to the holder.

Comment: You can implement it in EventHolder. It wont be different. I just worked it out off the cuff, so you may have to make slight adjustments to suit your case! But just shoot if you need further elaboration :))

Comment: I sort of understand what setTag() is supposed to be doing, but you defined holder in the onClick() method, and Android studio doesn't like that. Where should it be declared? Also, I tried to @Override onClick(), but the EventViewHolder class doesn't like that either. I'm assuming it wants it outside of the onClickListener declaration?

Comment: My bad, I was using thinking of a listview. Have updated my code for a recyclerview and you don't need a setTag in this case.